# Condtional statement execution in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

New to SQL and Sqlite, I'm afraid. I need to delete a row from table A, but only if that row isn't referenced in table B. So, I guess I need to do something like this:

```
delete from tableA 
   where (col1 = 94) and 
   (select count(*) from tableB (where col2 = 94) = 0);
```

What's the right way to do this?

Alternatively, I could just do this from C in two steps, first checking that the row isn't referenced, and then deleting it. Would this be better? I'm hesitant to do this because I would need to put an `sqlite3_mutex` around several steps in the C code, which might be less efficient that executing a single more complex statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is pretty close.  The parentheses are in the wrong place:

```
delete from tableA 
   where (col1 = 94) and 
         (select count(*) from tableB where col2 = 94) = 0;
```

For instance, SQL doesn't allow a paren before the `where`.

I would however suggest that you learn about foreign keys.  These are a useful construct in SQL.  The SQLite documentation is [here](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html).

A foreign key constraint would have the database do this check automatically whenever a row is being deleted from `tableA`.  The `delete` would return an error, but it would make sense -- something like "you can't delete this row because another row references it".

Answer (score 1):

```
delete tableA
from tableA 
left join tableB on tableA.col1 = tableB.col2
where tableB.col2 is null
and tableA.col1 = 94
```

You can `left join` the two tables and delete only those where the link could not be established between them (`tableB.col2 is null`).

Alternatively you can do

```
delete from tableA 
where col1 = 94
and not exists
(
   select 1 from tableB where col2 = 94
)
```